# How to convert a column of DataTable to a List

Tags: c#, .net, list, datatable

I have a DataTable with multiple columns. I want to get a `List<String>` out of first column of DataTable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 94):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dt = new DataTable
    {
        Columns = { { "Lastname",typeof(string) }, { "Firstname",typeof(string) } }
    };
    dt.Rows.Add("Lennon", "John");
    dt.Rows.Add("McCartney", "Paul");
    dt.Rows.Add("Harrison", "George");
    dt.Rows.Add("Starr", "Ringo");

    List<string> s = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[0].ToString()).ToList();

    foreach(string e in s)
        Console.WriteLine(e);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Is anyone else getting a ReadOnly error on Columns?

Comment: how to retrieve data from a column "name"?

Comment: @JerryGoyal Late reply, but for anyone else wondering just replace `x[0]` with `x["Lastname"]` . Lastname being the name of the column we're interested in.

Answer (score 62):

```
var list = dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    .Select(dr => dr.Field<string>(columnName)).ToList();
```

[**Edit**:  Add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` to your project if this does not compile]

Comment: AsEnumerable() works on a DataTable as well.

var list = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>(columnName)).ToList();

Comment: If `DataTable.AsEnumerable()` does not compile, add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions to your project.

Comment: What if you don't know the `columnName`?

Comment: I would choose AsEnumerable() method instead of this. This is like holding the right ear with left hand.

Answer (score 9):

Here you go.

```
           DataTable defaultDataTable = defaultDataSet.Tables[0];
           var list = (from x in defaultDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    where x.Field<string>("column1") == something
                    select x.Field<string>("column2")).ToList();
```

If you need the first column

```
           var list = (from x in defaultDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    where x.Field<string>(1) == something
                    select x.Field<string>(1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you need?

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    myList.Add((int)row[0]);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is almost correct except, question is asking for names or `List<String>`

Answer (score 5):

I do just like below, after you set your column AsEnumarable you can sort, order or how you want.

```
 _dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(p => p.Field<string>("ColumnName")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

I make a sample for you , and I hope this is helpful...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cols = new string[] { "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5" };

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (var col in cols)
            table.Columns.Add(col);

        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" });

        foreach (var col in cols)
        {
            var results = from p in table.AsEnumerable()
                          select p[col];

            Console.WriteLine("*************************");
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Very Simple Code to iterate datatable and get columns in list.

2.code ==>>>

```
 foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataTable.Columns)
 {
    var list = dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
     .Select(dataRow => dataRow.Field<string> 
       (dataColumn.ToString())).ToList();
 }
```

Comment: might want to mention that this 'simple' code requires .Net 4.5 or higher AND a nuget package which you have to install via "Install-Package System.Data.DataSetExtensions -Version 4.5.0"